# PyTorch Conv1d parameters

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, conv1d

I am trying to use 1D convolution in order to classify a set of time signals.
Every data unit I need to classify is made out of 65 different time series, each one contains 50 time samples, so if I write:

```
dataset = MyDataset(train,y_train_one_hot)
a,b = dataset[1]
print(a.shape)
```

I will get:
`[56,50]`.

I want to run 1D convolutional filters on each one of the channels.  Problem is I cant get right the inputs of the first `nn.Conv1d` layer - right now I am using:

`self.c1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=56 , out_channels=100 , kernel_size=ks1)`

but when I run the model with a batch size of 100, the input becomes of the shape `[100,56,50]` and I get only one prediction for a batch size of 100 (instead of 100X3).  Can anyone help with the right syntax?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
>>> conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=56 , out_channels=100, kernel_size=3)
>>> input = torch.randn(100, 56, 50)
>>> output = conv(input)
>>> output.shape
torch.Size([100, 100, 48])
```

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for the answer.  My problem was due to wrong reshaping of my tensor between the convolutional and the linear dense layers.